# Compiling c code to a Dynamic-Link-Library

Tags: c, dll, squeak

I have a .c file generated from Squeak that I need to compile to a dll for use as a plugin, but I don't know how. I have tried searching the internet, but all I can find is information on how to compile c# and c++ to a dll. The code that was generated is as follows:

```
/* Automatically generated from Squeak on (13 July 2016 9:46:45 pm) */

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(Win32)
 #ifdef __cplusplus
  #define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
 #else
  #define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
 #endif /* C++ */
#else
 #define DLLEXPORT
#endif /* WIN32 */

#include "sqVirtualMachine.h"

/* memory access macros */
#define byteAt(i) (*((unsigned char *) (i)))
#define byteAtput(i, val) (*((unsigned char *) (i)) = val)
#define longAt(i) (*((int *) (i)))
#define longAtput(i, val) (*((int *) (i)) = val)

#include <string.h>

/*** Variables ***/
struct VirtualMachine* interpreterProxy;
const char *moduleName = "TestPlugin 13 July 2016 (e)";

/*** Functions ***/
DLLEXPORT int primitiveAdd(void);
DLLEXPORT int primitiveFetchString(void);
DLLEXPORT int setInterpreter(struct VirtualMachine* anInterpreter);

DLLEXPORT int primitiveAdd(void) {
    int operand1;
    int operand2;
    int result;

    operand1 = interpreterProxy->stackIntegerValue(1);
    operand2 = interpreterProxy->stackIntegerValue(0);
    if (interpreterProxy->failed()) {
        return 0;
    }
    result = operand1 + operand2;
    interpreterProxy->popthenPush(3, ((result << 1) | 1));
    return 0;
}

DLLEXPORT int primitiveFetchString(void) {
    int in;
    int i;
    int count;
    int resultOop;
    char* src;
    char* dst;
    char s0[] = "zero";
    char s1[] = "non-zero";

    in = interpreterProxy->stackIntegerValue(0);
    if (interpreterProxy->failed()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (in == 0) {
        src = s0;
    } else {
        src = s1;
    }
    count = strlen(src);
    resultOop = interpreterProxy->instantiateClassindexableSize(interpreterProxy->classString(), count);
    dst = ((char *) (interpreterProxy->firstIndexableField(resultOop)));
    for (i = 0; i <= (count - 1); i += 1) {
        dst[i] = (src[i]);
    }
    interpreterProxy->popthenPush(2, resultOop);
    return 0;
}

DLLEXPORT int setInterpreter(struct VirtualMachine* anInterpreter) {
    int ok;

    interpreterProxy = anInterpreter;
    ok = interpreterProxy->majorVersion() == VM_PROXY_MAJOR;
    if (ok == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    ok = interpreterProxy->minorVersion() >= VM_PROXY_MINOR;
    return ok;
}
```

Note: This is just the TestPlugin code; I will actually be building a dll like this in order to speed up areas of my squeak code that run slow in squeak.

Answer (score 1):

Your first stop should be the [OpenSmalltalk virtual machine repository](https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/opensmalltalk-vm). The repository contains comprehensive documentation on how the virtual machine and its plugins are being compiled. If you want to distribute your plugin with the virtual machine then this is likely what you'll need.

On the other hand, you can simply compile the plugin yourself and copy it to the plugins directory. The VM will try to load the plugin upon request and can find it as the plugin directory is in its search path. To compile the plugin by yourself you will need a build toolchain. This can be anything (Visual Studio, XCode, autotools etc.) that generates shared libraries.

There are some things you need to keep in mind:

1. compile as shared and universal
2. compile to 32-bit
3. in case of C++: export the symbols to prevent name mangling

The complexity of the build script depends on the library that you want to compile. For a rather complex build script (for windows) of a plugin generated during VM compilation you can check out the [CMake script for libgit2](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm/blob/spur64/mc/CMakeLibGit2.package/CMWin32LibGit2.class/instance/build.st) used by the PharoVM.

Unfortunately, there is no silver bullet to shared library compilation. As the requirements of the library and its users change, so does the build process and its complexity. This is especially true for dependencies (e.g. when using pkg-config to search common installation paths for required libraries). Judging from your code however, I think it shouldn't be a big problem. My recommendation: take the time to create a [CMake](https://cmake.org) script for your plugin. It may be harder than running the compiler by hand but it serves as documentation on how to perform the compilation and will be a big help if you ever need to compile on or for another platform.